# Como mudar o src de uma <script> usando jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, link

Como eu posso fazer a mudança do valor do atributo `href` de um `<link>` e do `src` de um `<script>`.

Problema real, possuo duas telas que estão em níveis diferentes (pastas diferentes),
na qual ambas são acessadas pelo `window.load` que fica dentro da modal na `option Open`.

traduzindo, na primeira tela eu acesso a modal e os arquivos de css e javascript externos são acessados por 2 níveis acima `../../` e na segunda tela são acessados com três níveis `../../../`

Exemplo:

jQuery:

```
$("#pesquisaClienteCss").attr("href","../../view/css/pesquisaCliente.css");
```

html:

```
<link id="pesquisaClienteCss" href="../../view/css/pesquisaCliente.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Preciso que quando for ter um `$("#pesquisaCliente).dialog("open");` o `attr` modifique o `href` do link aumentando um nível de pasta `../` conseguiram compreender?

Comment: Os caminhos devem comecar com `/` para serem relativos à origen (root). Aí fica mais fácil trabalhar e não precisa de `../../`. Já tentou assim?

Comment: Não faz muito sentido trocar o src de uma tag script. O script antigo não é descarregado da memória, e não sei nem se o novo seria carregado.

Comment: Isso me dá uma forte impressão de ser um **[Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/)**.

Comment: Compreendo Bacco, estou querendo falar da solução em vez do problema,  o meu problema e o seguinte, eu possuo uma modal de pesquisa de clientes que é acessada por duas telas, clientes e relatorios que possuem niveis de pastas diferentes, acontece que, para o nivel cliente os links de css e javascript funcionam perfeitamente, porém no nivel de relatórios eles não são encontrados,  sendo encontrados somente um nível acima ../../../

Comment: E não dá pra simplesmente colocar o CSS respectivo no source de cada modal?

Comment: não entendi, pode me mostrar um exemplo ?

Comment: Teria que ver como é que vc ta fazendo no caso prático, senao fica dificil. Pq vc nao edita a pergunta e mostra trechos relevantes de como faz a carga no caso real, e de como é um modal desses? Assim a comunidade toda pode ajudar. Lembre-se que vc sabe como tao as coisas aí, e a gente só sabe o que estiver escrito na pergunta.

Comment: Ficar subindo de volta na árvore de diretórios costuma ser o [caminho para loucura](http://crappycode.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/wp-load-php-i-will-find-you/)... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de se resolver é colocar todos os seus scripts importantes em um caminho conhecido, e usar caminhos absolutos. Por exemplo, ao invés de:

```
<script src="../foo/bar.js"></script>
```

Use:

```
<script src="http://teusite.com/foo/bar.js"></script>
```

Que aí não importa que página vai abrir, o script sempre vai ser carregado corretamente. Existe outra alternativa. Você pode omitir o domínio e o protocolo e começar o caminho com "/" que dá no mesmo:

```
<script src="/foo/bar.js"></script>
```

Isso tem a vantagem de ser mais portável.

Ok, nem sempre é possível. Nesses casos o código server side é seu amigo. Se você usa alguma tecnologia server side (Java, Ruby, ASP.NET, PHP...) você pode montar a tag `script` dinamicamente com o caminho correto. Por exemplo, em .NET você faria algo do tipo:

```
<script src='<% #Eval("Caminho") %>'></script>
```

Note que essa variável `caminho`, bem como a estrutura que a contém, é definida em outro ponto.

Ou, com SharePoint:

```
<script src="~sitecollection/foo/bar.js"></script>
```

Boa sorte!